# Issue with displating output... (Creating nodes)

Tags: c

I have created a code to create nodes and delete them. It can also display certain nodes by index number. I have created a struct named NODE with the following values: firstname, lastname, PUID, age, next pointer.
The problem is that some of the nodes will display firstname properly while some doesn't when I display the node...

The below code is the function for displaying the saved nodes.

```
void LookUpByIndex(NODE* head, int index) {
    NODE* current = head;
    int count = 0;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        if (count == index)
        {
            printf("Node At index:\nFirst Name: %s\nLast Name: %s\nPUID: %s\nAge: %d\n", current->firstName, current->lastName, current->PUID, current->age);
            return;
        }
        count++;
        current = current->next;
    }
    printf("Error! Please Try Another Index.");
    return;
}
```

The below code is how the function is called:

```
 printf("Please Enter index: ");
            scanf("%d", &index);
            printf("\n");
            LookUpByIndex(head, index);
            break;
```

Below is the struct:

```
typedef struct node {
    char firstName[20];
    char lastName[20];
    char PUID[10];
    int age;
    struct node* next;
}NODE;
```

The function to create the node is below:

```
NODE* CreateListNode(NODE* new, char* firstName, char* lastName, char* PUID, int age){
    new = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    strcpy(new->firstName, firstName);
    strcpy(new->lastName, lastName);
    strcpy(new->PUID, PUID);
    new->age = age;
    new->next = NULL;
    return new;
}
```

and below is calling the function:

```
                printf("Please Enter First Name: ");
                scanf("%s", firstName);
                printf("Please Enter Last name: ");
                scanf("%s", lastName);
                printf("Please Enter PUID: ");
                scanf("%s", PUID);
                printf("Please Enter Age: ");
                scanf("%d", &age);
                printf("\n");
                head = CreateListNode(head, firstName, lastName, PUID, age);
                printf("Node has been created:\nFirst Name: %s\nLast Name: %s\nPUID: %s\nAge: %d\n", head->firstName, head->lastName, head->PUID, head->age);
```

Comment: It sounds like the part that is creating the list is wrong. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

you are not connecting the  nodes when you have 2nd and 3rd node, change your `CreateListNode` like this

```
NODE* CreateListNode(NODE* new, char* firstName, char* lastName, char* PUID, int age){
    if(new == NULL)
    {
        new = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        strcpy(new->firstName, firstName);
        strcpy(new->lastName, lastName);
        strcpy(new->PUID, PUID);
        new->age = age;
        new->next = NULL;
    }else{
        NODE* curr = new;
        NODE* temp = NULL;
        
        while(curr->next != NULL)
             curr = curr->next;

        temp = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        strcpy(temp->firstName, firstName);
        strcpy(temp->lastName, lastName);
        strcpy(temp->PUID, PUID);
        temp->age = age;
        curr->next = temp;

    }
    return new;
}
```